# How to make a sub-menu disappear after its clicked

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Basically, I am trying to get the menu to disappear when clicking a link. Here is an example site that demonstrates my problem:

> http://themeforest.net/item/square-responsive-admin-app-with-angularjs/full_screen_preview/7511722

- click the hamburger symbol
- hover over 'UI Kit'
- Click multiple links in the sub menu

As you can see when you click any of the links, the sub menu does not disappear. How can I make it disappear. I am using angular as my front end framework.

Comment: You could just do a this and addClass then make the added class visible and all submenu visible if that class is there. Minimal css and Minimal jquery